# Filtering SQL Queries Using PHP

Tags: php, sql, select

I have been searching for a while on a way to select certain columns (fields) in SQL.

What I am trying to do is this... Lets say I have a table with 200 columns of data. I want to select an entire row but only the last 197 columns of data. Leaving out the first 3 columns that have dates and ID's.

It would be very time consuming to type out the 197 field names I wanted the data from. There has to be some easier way of doing it.

Any help or suggestions to point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Which database are you using? If it is MySQL, I would use `DESCRIBE` command.

Comment: Yes I am using MYSQL. I forgot to add that tidbit. I am relatively new to PHP still and trying to understand some of the more complex parts of the language. IMHO it would have made sense if they included a "SELECT * EXCEPT whatever WHERE xyz"... The EXCEPT would make things so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, try something like this:

```
<?php
$query = "
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `Table` 
WHERE `Field` NOT LIKE 'rowtoignore1' 
AND `Field` NOT LIKE 'rowtoignore2' 
AND `Field` NOT LIKE 'rowtoignore3'
";

$r = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$queryfields = "";

while($f = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) { 
  $queryfields .= "`{$f['Field']}`,";
}

$queryfields = substr($queryfields,0,strlen($queryfields)-1);

$query = "SELECT {$queryfields} FROM `Table` WHERE xyz";
?>
```

Comment: This is looking like what I want to try. But I am wondering what will occur if the "WHERE xyz" points to the columns I am filtering out? Will the query fail with an error or will it work? Basically I am trying to fetch all the fields and filter out the first 3 ID fields so they are not part of the array when I display(loop) the results.

Comment: that should work without any trouble, but if they are just ID fields, they're unlikely to be very computationally heavy and you may want to consider simply ignoring these fields in your loop :)

Comment: That would be another way to do it. I have also searched on ways to filter the loop but haven't seen much out there. It seems most websites tend to just repeat what others have suggested. It becomes very repetitive and un-informative after a while. Any suggestions on the best way to filter the ID fields in a loop?

Comment: that really depends on what your loop is doing, but you could do something like

    $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`) or die(mysql_error());
    while($f = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) { 
        foreach($f as $key=>$value) { 
            if($key == "fieldtoignore1" OR $key == "fieldtoignore2" OR $key == "fieldtoignore3") continue; 
            echo "{$key}: {$value}" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

Comment: Ok I appreciate that. I think I will try that loop and see if I can fine tune it for what I need. I have been trying to wrap my head around the "$f as $key=>value" for a few days and this gives me a new twist on it. So much more to learn and so little years left on planet earth.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL you can query the schema to get a column name by index, so you could use an iterative PHP routine to build your query, but it would require 197 select statements before you could run the one you really want. Messy and inefficient.

It seems simpler to do a `SELECT *` and then ignore the first three columns. If you use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` you can get the columns you want easily. Take a look at:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

If i am doing this task, i won't exclude the first 3 columns . If the 3 columns contains lengthy text / blob , then you could avoid, else better fetch those 200 columns .

Using this function mysql_list_fields()  fetch fields corresponding to a table , and customize the select query to include required fields